# Bandwidth Aggregation Possible in Mikrotik Router?

Tags: networking, router

In Mikrotik RouterOS, can I aggregate multiple WANs Bandwidth and use it for one User? For an example, I have two WAN links (5 Mbps and 5 Mbps) is it possible to use the total bandwidth (10 Mbps) in one PC/User?

Answer (score 0):

No, aggregation of links increases total capacity, not speed of a single conversation, plus you need the devices at both ends to support the aggregation protocol.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation
https://serverfault.com/questions/569721/can-bonding-2-interfaces-double-the-speed